# What is the relationship between the Loc-Nar and the Taarakians?

Tags: heavy-metal

In the animated film [**Heavy Metal**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy_Metal_(film)) (1981), a young girl is held prisoner in her house by an evil glowing artifact called the Loc-Nar. While captive, the girl is forced to witness several stories showing how the Loc-Nar has travelled across the universe and brought misfortune to those around it. Oddly enough, the stories appear to be happening AS the story is told, with the Loc-Nar growing in size and strength as each story progresses.

The final story, Taarna, details how a woman warrior named Taarna - the last of the Taarakian warriors - finally stands up to the forces of the Loc-Nar and destroys it, sacrificing both herself and her companion (a bird-like mount) to do so. The end of the film then reveals that

> the girl in the house escapes only to find a bird-mount like Taarna's waiting for her. As she mounts it and flies off, her hair turns white like Taarna's and she now has the tattoo of a Taarakian warrior on her neck.

Has any additional material - interviews, comics, articles in [Heavy Metal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy_Metal_(magazine)) magazine - explained this? The wiki article states that Taarna was inspired by the [Arzach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzach) stories of Moebius, but I'm a little leary of searching for that given Moebius' NSFW work.